# Why libtorch tensor value assignment takes so much time?

Tags: c++, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, libtorch

I just assign 10000 values to a tensor:

```
clock_t start = clock();
torch::Tensor transform_tensor = torch::zeros({ 10000 });
for (size_t m = 0; m < 10000 m++)
    transform_tensor[m] = int(m);
clock_t finish = clock();
```

And it takes 0.317s. If I assign 10,000 to an array or a vector, the time cost will be less.
Why tensor takes so much time? Can the time cost be decreased?

Comment: How much less exactly ?

Comment: Using vector only takes 0.003s.

Comment: Yep indeed, and even creating a tensor with `torch::arange(1, 10000, 1)` which should be the fastest way to do it in torch is order of magnitude slower than the vector initialization ; I cannot explain it, maybe you should try asking directly on the pytorch forums ?

Comment: Hi, I am running into a similar issue. Could you make this assignment faster?